# C# error: Mailbox unavailable. Client does not have permission to send as this sender

Tags: c#, smtp, credentials, smtpclient

I have a simple C# application which sends email from "noreply@domain.com" with an attachment. If I use my own email address then it works well. Any other email, error in result. Messaging server team cannot solve as they did not find any problem in server setting on config. My application is very simple but not working. Here is the code.

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
AutoTCs AutoTC = new AutoTCs();
                AutoTC.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBServer"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBName"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBUserId"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBPwd"]);

//CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
Stream ms;
ms = (Stream)AutoTC.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
Attachment attch = new Attachment(ms, "AutoTC_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day + "_AM.pdf");
MailMessage emsg = new MailMessage(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FromAddress"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ToAddress"], "Auto TC Report " + DateTime.Now.Month + "/" + DateTime.Now.Day + " AM", "Please find the Auto TC report ");

string[] arInfo = new string[4];
// define which character is seperating fields
char[] splitter = { ';' };
arInfo = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CCAddress"].ToString().Split(splitter);
                for (int x = 0; x < arInfo.Length; x++)
                {
                    emsg.CC.Add(arInfo[x]);
                }
                emsg.Attachments.Add(attch);
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP"]);
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
//smtp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
//smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(emsg);
```

And in from address I simply putting "noreply@noreply.domain.com"

> Giving this error "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was 5.7.1
>   Client does not have permission to send as this sender"

I checked with other port number 25 but then "channel no opens" kind of error message appear.

Comment: sounds like you don't have permission to send emails from any other email address except your own. The error message seems quite clear about that. I very much doubt it's the fault of your code. I would guess that maybe the server team don't deem that to be a problem because that's how they expect their security to work? I don't know what kind of mailserver it is, but presumably you'd need some extra rights or prvileges in order to be allowed to send mail on behalf of someone else.

Comment: The from address in the email must be the same email address as the email server account.

Comment: The from address is derived from the default credentials and you must use the default credentials to get the password through the network.

Comment: I have tried every thing I know. Used different credentials, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very unambiguous - you (as the authenticated SMTP user) have no right to send on behalf of that user. If you are using Exchange, make sure your mailbox has the Send and Send As rights on behalf of that mailbox.

`UseDefaultCredentials` is also not a good idea - try to explicitly specify the credentials.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I am using Outlook and there is no property "SendAs" just checked. Where to look for such property or rights.

Comment: I did not imply there is such a property in Outlook. I meant the :"send as" right in the Exchange Admin console, if Exchange is what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

From add Roles and Features wizard, select SMTP Server to check it.

[image]